# HTML5 elements in Internet Explorer: runtime insertion

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, html

I have a problem with using HTML5 elements in Internet Explorer 7 and up (not testing IE6). I know that by default, IE refuses to recognize common HTML5 elements like "article" or "header" without the use of a Javascript "shiv". I've used modernizr (http://www.modernizr.com) to force IE to recognize these elements to that I can apply CSS styles to them. So far so good.

The problem now is that the application uses Javascript to fetch certain HTML fragments (containing HTML5 markup) and inserts them into the document at run-time. On all other browsers, this works flawlessly, but in IE, elements inserted at runtime can't be styled with CSS.

Here's an example of the chunk of markup that I'm injecting into the page:

```
<article id="block-1" class="block">
  <a href="#">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Text</p>
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100" width="100" height="100" alt="placeholder" />
  </a>
</article>
```

I've tested my theory by replacing the article tag by a common div, which seems to solve the problem for now, at the expense of semantic markup. But I'd like to know if there are any more future-proof workarounds.

Comment: Do there exist an article element in the document from the beginning? Reason I ask is that in theory those libs maybe only run document.createElement for elements that can be found onDOMReady.

Comment: Yes, there are. And they're styled correctly but all future elements aren't. I know, it's baffling.

Comment: don't be baffled; it's IE - it's not supposed to work properly  ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this will help: http://jdbartlett.github.com/innershiv/

innerShiv is a function which takes your HTML string, adds it to a hidden document-appended element in IE, and returns an IE-safe document fragment or collection.

Comment: This looks very promising. I will give it a shot and report back with my findings.

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd just use a `<div>` and live with it.

The purpose of semantic markup is to help the search engines understand what the page content is about. Dynamic content like this which is loaded after the main page load may not be seen by the search engines, so semantic markup is perhaps a moot point.

Comment: Oh it's a lot more than search engines, it's so you can write documents with a meaningful structure and not just have them be a collection of "stuff"

Comment: I'd recommend sticking with `<div class="article">` as recommended for cases where you care about old browsers. Then the query selector `article` becomes `.article`, which isn't too bad.

Comment: @JohnB - agreed, semantic markup is a good thing, but practically if it doesn't work in this case, it's not going to make a massive amount of difference to the world.

Comment: It does mean that we can't use HTML5 markup in any situation where it might be injected as a page-fragment, which is ludicrous. What about a blog with AJAX pagination for the next/previous posts? Those posts couldn't contain any new semantic markup whatsoever if you want to support IE...

Comment: @gillesv: You're dealing with a browser that has no concept whatever of HTML5. I think we're quite lucky it works at all, but if there are cases where it still has issues, it shouldn't be a surprise.

Comment: When IE is considered, this is the cheapest solution to at least apply to a certain element.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the HTML5 elements like `header`, `article` etc are `inline`.

In your CSS file, you should set `display: block` rule for them.

`article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section 
{
    display: block;
}`

Hope this helps you!

Comment: This is nothing to do with what he's experiencing. He's just not being able to style dynamically inserted items in IE.

Comment: Yeah, I already have an HTML5 reset block in my CSS files so this isn't the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.