# Nested HTML elements with display:none not behaving in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, html

I'm using jQuery to fade in an `<article>` element which contains a `<section>` element.

Outside element is `display:none`, `position:fixed`, and `z-index:5`. Inside element is `position:absolute`.

Basically the article gives a frame and the inside section holds the content and has a scrollbar.

I'm fading in the outside element and expecting the inside to follow suit.

In IE9+, FF, and Chrome it works as expected.

In IE8- it does not. The outside article doesn't fade in at all - remains invisible, and the inside section is positioned relative to the browser frame and is always visible. Other elements on the page are all skewed and the page becomes mostly non-functional.

Code samples:

```
article
{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
}

section
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

and

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <article id="contentFrame">
      <section id="content">
        Lorem Ipsum
      </section>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

and

```
$("#contentFrame").fadeIn(2000);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE8 and below does not support HTML5 tags such as `article` and `section`.

[HTML5 elements CSS & Javascript interaction in IE8 and below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931167/html5-elements-css-javascript-interaction-in-ie8-and-below)

[HTML5 elements in Internet Explorer: runtime insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849219/html5-elements-in-internet-explorer-runtime-insertion)

Comment: I have created a new jsFiddle with divs replacing the article/section tags. It works better now, but the inner div is always visible regardless of the current opacity of the outer div. See: http://jsfiddle.net/MBNsd/

Comment: This is the way animation works in IE. http://jsfiddle.net/E5wGq/3/ — works as expected. First delay added for notability only.

Comment: Ok, I can do that. But this is a hugely simplified example. In my real page I have countless nested elements in dozens of levels inside #eSection. Do I need to fadeIn() each element in each level, or is it because #eSection is position:absolute which is making IE do this? Will I have to fadeIn() all position:absolute descendants?

Comment: Thanks Artem. How would this affect performance? If I have a bajillion descendant elements and the javascript engine is frantically trying to animate their opacity, would the average computer stutter? My dev machine is a beast so it runs quite smooth for me. Is there any performance difference between your method and just animating in the parent element like in my original example? The user sees the same thing, but the JS is animating all descendant elements vs just one.

Comment: Yes, selectors and animation in IE are damn slow, especially in a large DOM. Check out this presentation for jQuery performance tips and tricks: http://www.slideshare.net/AddyOsmani/jquery-proven-performance-tips-tricks. The first thing I would use is to cache the container for selectors: http://jsfiddle.net/E5wGq/27/